# Деепричастие "бьясь"

Tags: деепричастия

Мало информации по этому слову. Употребить возможно? Несёт ли оно в себе смысл "сражаясь" или подразумевает только "ударяясь"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**биться**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=vFimCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B1%D1%8C%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=wlLrxnve0X&sig=b6IybnQyCPf_1x0bhrZTz2RR6bo&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNj6OR0cTbAhUBbFAKHTb3CrgQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B1%D1%8C%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9&f=false), бьюсь, бьётся, *пов.* бейся, *деепр. неупотр. || в текстах отмеч. деепр. **бьясь, биясь***.
[бить, бью, бьёт, *пов.* бей; *деепр. неупотр. || в текстах отмеч. деепр. бья, бия*]

*Дни лета

Клонились к осени. Дышал

Ненастный ветер. Мрачный вал

Плескал на пристань, ропща пени

И **бьясь** об гладкие ступени,

Как челобитчик у дверей

Ему не внемлющих судей.*
А. С. Пушкин. Медный всадник (1833)

"Бьясь" в значении "сражаясь" встречается в современных текстах, но очень редко:

*А Пендрагон погиб в бою,

За землю **бьясь** с врагом свою,

Стрела с ладьи норманн, звеня,

Пробила сердце короля.*
[**А. Миронов. Рыцари короля Артура**](https://www.stihi.ru/2010/07/10/250) (2010)

*И господа писаки, толкаясь локтями и **бьясь** насмерть с бывшими членами Государственной Думы у трапа последнего парохода...*
Дмитрий Быков. "Новая газета" (2010)

Answer (score 3):

В редких случаях использовалось и в значении "биться с врагом":

> Бывшие там с монастырским слугою Пименом Тененевым люди твердо стали
> на пригорке у рва против врагов, **биясь** с литовцами и казаками.
> (Сказание Авраамия Палицына)
>
> Седмь лет мы в их полях стояли
>
> Со обнаженными мечьми,
>
> Когда срацины обуяли,
>
> **Биясь** с российскими людьми.
>
> (М. Н. Муравьёв, Ода Екатерине II)

Comment: У Вас в примере "биясь". Форма кажется устарелой. Вариант "бьясь" для современного звучания возможен?

Comment: В словаре Еськовой  (Словарь трудностей русского языка) деепричастная форма (биясь и бьясь) обозначена как _неупотребляемая_, но встречающаяся в текстах. У Ожегова есть только "биясь (устар.)". Поэтому если и устарело, то вряд ли сменилось новым ("бьясь" есть и в _старых_ поэтических текстах, возможно в порядке поэтической вольности). "Биясь" есть во множестве современных книг (из классиков - у Ильфа и Петрова), просто в значении, поставленном в вопросе, встречается редко.